# Add new method to an interface which is directly implemented by many classes

Tags: java, interface

I have a small question on java interfaces

Is there any way to add a new method to java interface without modifying the classes that are implementing it.

condition is that I should not introduce new interface

Comment: Defender / Default methods are being added in Java 1.8 which will allow you to add a new method and default implementation to an interface.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is there any way to add a new method to java interface without modifying the classes that are implementing it.

No.

> condition is that I should not introduce new interface

If the condition also includes not modifying the many classes that directly implement the interface, you have been given an impossible task.

This is the reason why interfaces are often accompanied by abstract `Adapter` classes, that implement all the methods in a do-nothing way. Implementation classes then extend the adapter rather than implementing the interface, so that if you need to add an interface you only need to modify the interface and the adapter.

Comment: +1 except for that last paragraph. I'd argue that using an `Adapter` with a do-nothing implementation is a Very Bad Idea. The interface is a contract. Implementing a method of it without actually performing the work it's contracted to do breaks that contract.

Comment: You would be arguing with the authors of all the adapters in `java.awt.event` then. Feel free.

Comment: I'd agree, with one caveat. Adapters are useful for listeners where people are often implementing the interface but only interested in one or two of the callbacks.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying to do is fundamentally impossible. Unless (as was just pointed out in the comments) you use Java 8.

Java 8 has introduced a concept of default or defender methods that allow you to add a method to an interface and provide a default implementation of that method within the interface.

http://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/java-8-explained-default-methods/

**The rest of the answer applies to any version of Java before 8:**

An interface describes the methods in a class. If you add a new method to an interface then all classes that implement the interface must implement the method. Unless by some stroke of luck the method you are adding already exists in every single implementing class this is just impossible without either adding a new interface or changing the classes.

If your interface were an Abstract Class then you could add a stub method that does nothing and allow that to be overridden but interfaces have no concept of optional methods.

Comment: It is fundamentally impossible until java 1.8 :)

Comment: Defender / default methods

Comment: Added that into my answer.

Answer (score 0):

By using abstract class we can solve this problem.

```
   interface A{
     void a();
     void b();
    }

  Class a implement A 

  Class b implement A ...
```

if any new method arrive to create an abstract class and add that method into it

```
 abstract class adapter { 
       abstract void c();
     }
```

now extend this adapter class for necessary classes..